# Question for stripe-webhooks with node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, webhooks

I just watched a youtube to create a payment system with stripe API, react, and node.js. I am not  sure what webhook is and the purpose on this stirpe api. This code already checks the error, but why webhook is necessary and how does it work? I saw bunch of node.js stripe webhook examples but still could not understand. I am a super beginner

Here is my code

React(index.html)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout"

function App() {

  const [product, setstate] = useState({
    name: "React from FB",
    price: 10,
    productBy:"facebook"
  })

  const makePayment = token => {
    const body = {
      token, 
      product
    }
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    return fetch('http://localhost:8282/payment', {
      method: "POST",
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response =>{
      console.log("RESPONSE", response)
      const{status} = response;
      console.log("STATUS", status)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="#"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>

      <StripeCheckout
      stripeKey="KEY"
      token={makePayment}
      name="Buy React"
      amount = {product.price * 100}>
        <button className="btn-large pink"> buy react is just {product.price}$</button>
      </StripeCheckout>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Node.js (index.js)

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const stripe = require('stripe')("KEY");
const uuid = require("uuid");

const app = express();


//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());


//routes
app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.send("It works!!!")
});

app.post("/payment", (req,res)=>{
    const{product, token} = req.body;
    console.log("PRODUCT", product);
    console.log("PRICE", product.price);
    const idempontencyKey = uuid();

    return stripe.customers.create({
        email: token.email,
        source: token.id
    }).then(customer => {
        stripe.charges.create({
            amount: product.price * 100,
            currency: 'usd',
            customer: customer.id,
            receipt_email: token.email,
            description: product.name,
            shipping: {
                name: token.card.name,
                address: {
                    country: token.card.address_country
                }
            }
        }, {idempontencyKey})
    })
    .then(result => res.status(200).json(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})

//listen
app.listen(8282, () =>{
    console.log("Listening at PORT 8282");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a decent explanation of what webhooks are: https://zapier.com/blog/what-are-webhooks/

Basically though: when you make a request to Stripe's API, you're asking for information, webhooks provide a way for Stripe to send information directly to your application as soon as it's available.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to integrate Stripe into your application.

#### Only Client-side handling

Stripe allows you to integrate a Checkout mechanism, where you only need to implement client code to perform payments.

Here is a reference for one time payments with only client-side code: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client

#### Client-side and Server-side

But there are sometimes usecase where client and server need to communicate with each other before/while a payment process (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder). For example if you don't manage your inventory with Stripe you will need some own logic on the server. One reason would be that you just want to offer Stripe just as a payment gateway for credit cards besides other payment methods like PayPal.

#### Webhooks

Well webhooks can be used in both cases. Webhooks allow you to let Stripe communicate with your backend server to inform you about succeeded payment, failed payments, customer updates, orders, billings and so on. By defining a webhook URL you can specify which events you want to receive from Stripe. You can then use events to update specified data in your database.

I assume one main idea is to avoid rate limits, because without webhooks your backend server may need to ask the Stripe API in a specified time interval or on trigger to let you send the latest informations of a specified product or customer. With the response of the API you are then able to update you own database.

Lets think about the case where you change a product in your Stripe Dashboard, then you will need to update as soon as possible 'manually' your own backend with a trigger or something else to display the latest changes to the visitors of your website. There is also Stripe Billing, which let you integrate recurring payments. In this case there are even more request to the Stripe API needed to keep you own database in track with the actual data.

For all this a webhook is very fancy. Why? You will need much less hits from you backend to the Stripe API, because Stripe will inform you about every change made in you Pricing, Products, Customer informations, inside your Stripe Dashboard. With this informations you can automate you backend much cleaner in my opinion, because the only job you have will be to check which events are sent to you server and how you can extract specified informations for your own need.

Here are the specified Stripe events https://stripe.com/docs/api/events.

Again it really depends on your usecase.